# ('The SQL contains 0 parameter markers, but 50 parameters were supplied', 'HY000') or TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable

Tags: python, mysql

```
import pyodbc,nltk,array
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Server=127.0.0.1;Port=3306;Database=information_schema;User=root; Password=1234;Option=3;')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute("use collegedatabase ;")
cursor.execute("select *  from sampledata ; ")
cnxn.commit()
s=[]
j=[]
x=[]
words = []
w = []
sfq = []
POS=[]
for entry in cursor:
        s.append(entry.injury_type),j.append(entry.injury_desc) 


from nltk.tokenize import PunktWordTokenizer
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
tokenizer = PunktWordTokenizer()
english_stops = set(stopwords.words('english'))
for i in range(0,26): # filter stop words
            tokenizer.tokenize(j[i])
            w.append([word for word in tokenizer.tokenize(j[i]) if word not in english_stops])

for a in range(0 , 26):#CONVERTING tokenzied text ito a string 
            sfq.append(" ".join(w[a])) 

from replacers import RegexpReplacer
replacer =  RegexpReplacer()
for a in range (0,26):#POS TAGGING
            replacer.replace(sfq[a])
            POS.append(tokenizer.tokenize(sfq[a]))                
            x.append(nltk.pos_tag(POS[a])) 
            cursor.executemany("update sampledata SET POS = %s where SRNO =%d",(x[a],a))
```

The error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Vaibhav\Dropbox\DUE BY MONDAY\tryingtofixerror.py", line 35, in 
    cursor.executemany("update sampledata SET POS = %s where SRNO =%d",(x[a],a))
ProgrammingError: ('The SQL contains 0 parameter markers, but 50 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')
```

After browsing for finding solution to the the problem I thought of replacing last line  (line 35)with this statement

```
cursor.executemany((u'update sampledata SET POS = %s where SRNO =%d'.encode('utf-8'),(x[a],a))(u'MO-MK25'.encode('utf-8')))
```

I do not know if I am progressing in right direction or not but going through so many websites and forums I got an hint that may be there is a indentation or comma error. I do not know what else to do. By the way, the error code generated is given below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Vaibhav\Dropbox\DUE BY MONDAY\tryingtofixerror.py", line 35, in 
    cursor.executemany((u'update sampledata SET POS = %s where SRNO =%d'.encode('utf-8'), (x[a],a)) (u'MO-MK25'.encode('utf-8')))
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

Comment: For one thing, the pyodbc docs say that it uses `?` for parameter substitution, not `%s`.

Comment: Please, use a less aggressive formatting for your question, calm down, read the answer, and try to understand the reason for your error.  Currently, you are guessing blindly, only making things worse!

Comment: That last error is happening because you are probably missing a comma or calling executemany incorrectly.  It looks to be attempting to treat `(u'update sampledata SET POS = %s where SRNO =%d'.encode('utf-8'), (x[a],a))` as a callable and pass `(u'MO-MK25'.encode('utf-8'))` to it.  That is certainly not what you were intending.

Answer (score 0):

The method `executemany(sql, seq_of_parameters)` executes the same SQL statement multiple times for a set of parameters.  Therefore, the second argument, `seq_of_parameters`, must be a sequence of parameter tuples, not just a single parameter tuple:

```
cursor.executemany("update sampledata SET POS = ? where SRNO = ?", [(x[a], a)])
```

If you pass just one tuple, the cursor will assume that the first item, `x[a]`, is a tuple of parameters.  I guess it is a string of 50 characters and gets interpreted as a sequence of 50 parameters, whereas the SQL string only expects 2.

Furthermore, notice that I used `?` as the placeholder symbol instead of `%s`, since the latter seems to be unsupported by PyODBC, as it reported that it expected 0 parameters.

In your case, you might want to use the `execute()` method in the loop, since you only want to run the statement once per iteration:

```
cursor.execute("update sampledata SET POS = ? where SRNO = ?", (x[a], a))
```

Comment: I tried using your suggestion and for me your suggestion was convincing but the following error was generated             Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Vaibhav\Dropbox\DUE BY MONDAY\tryingtofixerror.py", line 35, in <module>
    cursor.execute("update sampledata SET POS = ? where SRNO = ?", (x[a], a))
ProgrammingError: ('Invalid parameter type.  param-index=0 param-type=list', 'HY105')

Comment: @VaibhavChauhan: Please, you can read, right?  The error message clearly indicates that the first parameter is of the invalid type `list`.  So `x[a]` seems to be a list, but your database cannot store lists in a table column.  It should probably be an integer or string.  What exactly are you trying to insert into the database?

Comment: Right before your sql statement, try printing out the value of x[a] and confirming it is not a list

Comment: what I am trying to insert is a tokenized text into MySQL databases;so can you please suggest me a way of converting list item to a string and still staying in the last loop.

Comment: I don't know what `nltk.pos_tag()` returns.  If is a list of strings, you can probably store it as a comma-separated string as returned by `','.join(x[a])`, but this really depends on what you want to do with the data.

Comment: ok this is how my x[1] looks like                                  >>> x[1]
[('Discharge', 'NNP'), ('pipe', 'NN'), ('HFO', 'NNP'), ('purifier', 'NN'), ('parted', 'VBD'), ('junction', 'NN'), ('attempt', 'NN'), ('stop', 'NN'), ('leak.', 'NNP'), ('Chief', 'NNP'), ('Engineer', 'NNP'), ('Briefing', 'NNP'), ('Eyes/face', 'NNP'), ('affected', 'VBD'), ('heavy', 'JJ'), ('fuel', 'NN'), ('burst', 'NN'), ('pipe.', 'NNP'), ('Both', 'NNP'), ('eyes', 'VBZ'), ('got', 'VBN'), ('chemical', 'JJ'), ('irritation', 'NN'), ('heavy', 'JJ')......]

Comment: It tells you what is wrong in the error.  You are passing a list when it expects a value of a different type.  I didn't look to hard, but I'd investigate whether you want to be appending or assigning that list comprehension to w.  Also, better variable names will improve the readability of your code.

Comment: I tried using " ".join(x[1]) got following error             Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    " ".join(x[1])
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, tuple found

Comment: You are trying to join a list of tuples. If you only want the first index of each element you can try:  ' '.join(item[0] for item in x[1])

Comment: @sr2222 this is what exactly what I wanted to do and this is exactly what i wanted for so may days; thanks to everyone for their suggestion and ideas; and I will keep working on my programming skills so that i could ask more logical question :)

Comment: The part that confuses me is that it seems like you dont even know what data you want to store. Its apparently arbitrary for you if you are willing to join or cast whatever you can to a string. Figure out what data you want and learn about python data structures

Comment: To add to @jdi, you may be looking for .join((item[0] + ', ' + item[1]) for item in x[1]).  What exactly are you trying to get this to look like?

Comment: this is the line that changed made it worked                   cursor.execute("update sampledata SET POS = ? where SRNO = ?", (str(x[a])), a)

Comment: That is an extremely strange solution to your problem. All you did was store a string repr of a list of tuples. Of course that will work and store a string but is that really the data you wanted?

Comment: Substitute %s with ? works with my query pulling loop from mySQL. :) so happy ~