# How to use date range in python to pull /query data in mySQL

Tags: python, mysql, database, date

How can I pull data in mySQL by day using python date?
Say I want `day1` and `day2` ( or a day after `day1` ) iterate for `n` times

So I need the date in "where" SQL statement to look like below list in each iteration (`n` times )

```
day1 >= '2012-01-01'  and  day2 < '2012-01-02'    ( n = 1 )
day1 >= '2012-01-02'  and  day2 < '2012-01-03'    ( n = 2 )
.
.
day1 >= yesterday    and day2  < today            ( n times )
```

.

```
Start_date = '2012-01-01'   <- How can I write this in python
End_date = Today()   <- and this
```

So as to write:

```
for each iteration ..
    con.execute("select * from table where date >= day1 and date < day2" )
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to `datetime` module:-

```
import datetime
start = datetime.date(2012,01,01) 
next = start + datetime.date.resolution

while next <= datetime.date.today():
    print start, next

    con.execute("""
        select * from table where date >= %s and date < %s
    """, (start, next))

    start = next
    next = start + datetime.date.resolution
```

**IMPORTANT NOTICE**: I updated the answer to fix a serious problem. Never **ever** use string formatting (a.k.a. `%`) for building SQL queries since it is open to serious problems including *SQL injection*. Use `Python-<db_driver>` api where nearly all RDMBes offers the same syntax

```
execute("select * from blah where x=%s AND y=%s", (x, y))
                                     ^       ^  ^
                                     1       1  2
```

1] No quote, 
2] No string formatting

Comment: Actually , I am getting the syntax error " You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s and date < %s %(start, next)' the date is datetime format .. hmmm

Comment: found out that I have to change "%s" to "?" and this query will work. Based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9603616/the-sql-contains-0-parameter-markers-but-50-parameters-were-supplied-hy000

Comment: `start = datetime.date(2012,01,01)` gives **SyntaxError: invalid token** error.

It should be `start = datetime.date(2012,1,1)`

Answer (score 2):

Use the `datetime` class with the `strftime` function.

The `datetime` class is used to build an object which represents a specific date and time. The `strftime` function converts it to a specific string, according to the formatting you choose.

According to [MySQL's documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html), the standard datetime formatting is `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`.

Here's an example that should work:

```
day1 = datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 1).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
day2 = datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 2).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
con.execute("select * from table where date >= %s and date < %s", (day1, day2))
```

If you want to make additional queries, just create appropriate `datetime.datetime` objects on each round of your loop. For instance:

```
for i in xrange(1, 10):
    # ...
    day2 = datetime.datetime(2012, 1, i).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    # ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [datetime.date](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#date-objects) objects. They are wonderful things because with them you can:

- easily compute today (`dt.date.today()`),
- easily compute the next day (`start + dt.timedelta(days = 1)`,
- compare dates (e.g. `start < end`)
- feed them *directly* into `con.execute`. There is no
  need to pre-format them as strings.

---

```
import datetime as dt
start = dt.date(2012,1,1)
end = dt.date.today()

while start < end:
    nextday = start + dt.timedelta(days = 1)
    con.execute("select * from table where date >= %s and date < %s",
                (start, nextday))

    start = nextday
```

Comment: Remove the comma `,` and add a percent sign `%` in the `con.execute ` line, as the existing code does not frame the sql properly

Comment: I'm using the 2-argument form of `con.execute`. See [PEP 249](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/). This is the correct way of supplying arguments to a parametrized SQL statement. It is the preferred way of using `con.execute`, since it will protect you from [sql injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).